# Почему Nuget может не восстанавливать пакеты?

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, visual-studio-2019, tfs

В общем, стягиваю решение с TFS и перед мной пестрят ошибки, что нету Dapper'а в одном из проектов:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Dapper" version="1.60.1" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Dapper.Contrib" version="1.60.1" targetFramework="net452" />
</packages>
```

В настройках Nuget'а стоит автоматическая докачка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И только после того, как я вбиваю

> Update-Package –reinstall -ProjectName ProjectName

У меня выполняется скачка и при этом проект "пачкается" и говорится, что есть незакомиченные изменения...

Можно ли как-то сделать восстановления без пачканья?

Только изучить *.csproj и посмотреть, где ищет пакет проект, далее скачать пакет отдельно и выложить в ту папку?

Answer (score 0):

Если это гит, то может гитигнор уберет ненужные изменения: [Omitting NuGet packages in source control systems](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/packages-and-source-control)